# Why is my Sass not showing up when using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, gulp-sass

I am running Gulp version 4. I have a folder structure where all my code that I edit is in my src folder and all the code that gets minified, autoprefixed, etc. gets sent to my dist folder. For some reason when I open my file using BrowserSync all my changes that are made to my main.scss file get minified, autoprefixed to the dist/css/main.css file but the changes don't show up whenever BrowserSync is in effect. Here is my gulpfile.js, index.html, main.css, and main.scss.

Gulpfile.js

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const browserSync  = require('browser-sync').create();
const cleanCSS  = require( 'gulp-clean-css');
const sourcemaps  = require( 'gulp-sourcemaps');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

// Create a function named scss which applies all the changes to our scss folder and all .scss files in that folder
function scss() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
         .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
         .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
         .pipe(cleanCSS())
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
         .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}

/* Create a function that will compress our images */
/* function images() {
  return gulp.src('src/img/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe( imagemin([
          imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
          imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
          imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5})
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img/'))
} */



function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: './src'
    }
  });
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', scss);
  gulp.watch('src/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
  
}

exports.scss = scss;
exports.watch = watch;
```

src/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/main.css">
    <title>Gulp 4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">Gulp 4 Works</h1>
  
</body>
</html>
```

src/scss/main.scss

```
.heading {
background: green;
display: flex;


}
```

dist/css/main.css

```
.heading{background:green;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms- 
flexbox;display:flex}
/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbIm1haW4uY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBLFNBQ0UsV0FBWSxNQUNaLFFBQVMsWUFDVCxRQUFTLFlBQ1QsUUFBUyIsImZpbGUiOiJtYWluLmNzcyIsInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbXX0= */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function watch() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {

      // baseDir: './src',

      baseDir: "./",
      index: "src/index.html",
    }
  });
  gulp.watch('src/scss/**/*.scss', scss);
  gulp.watch('src/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
}
```

Note the changes I made to `baseDir` and adding the `index` server option.  I think your `index.html` is located in the src folder?

I ran your original code and the browser was always looking for the css file here:

```
http://localhost:3000/dist/css/main.css
```

which is problematic since your `main.css` is not located under the index.html file as browserSync seems to think.  Also use this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/main.css">
```

With the above you do not need to move your `index.html` file from the `src` folder.

Also, in your scss task, the `sourcemaps.init()` pipe should go before the `sass()` pipe

```
function scss() {
  return gulp.src('src/scss/**/*.scss')
         .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
         .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
         .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))         
         .pipe(cleanCSS())
         .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'))
         .pipe(browserSync.stream());
}
```

This last change has nothing to do with your original problem, but it is a change you will want to make.

Comment: Yes you are correct....it was looking for my index.html file and I had it inside of the src folder...and your solution worked. The only reason I put the index.html file inside of the src folder was because every other gulpfile.js I looked on Github it had it in that location. Would it be better for future reference if I just had it in the root with the gulpfile.js and package.json?

Comment: I have mine in the root, so I have never run into your particular problem before and no matter how many "././dist/css/main.css" I used the browser still always looked directly under the html file.  My site is really essentially a single page site.  So anything more complicated, I would say a "src" folder is the better practice for storing your html files.

Comment: Your problem wasn't really the location of your html file, but that browserSync was always looking for the css file relative to the "./src" folder which wouldn't work.  The changes I made changed that so everything is relative to the root folder "./".